# Confusion regarding range-based for loop in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

This code takes a string and then write outs the even and odd-positioned characters of the string as 2 separate strings separated by a space. I have solved the problem using standard for loop. But I am trying to use range-based for loop in it instead of the normal for loop (after getting fired up by Bjarne's 2017 CPPCON keynote). The normal for loop works fine and I have commented it in the following code-block.

Problem is: The code compiles with g++ -std=c+11 command, but the even and odd strings are coming out garbled and reads like binary files. Can you please explain what I am doing wrong and exactly what is happening here? A clear explanation will be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
    string S,even,odd;
    cout << "Enter a string:\n";
    cin.ignore();   // So that getline does not catch 
    //the eol character
    getline(cin,S);
    // for (int j=0; j<S.length(); j++){
    //     if(j==0 || j%2==0){even.push_back(S[j]);}
    //     else {odd.push_back(S[j]);}
    // }
    for (auto j : S){
        if(j==0 || j%2==0){even.push_back(S[j]);}
        else {odd.push_back(S[j]);}
    }
    cout << "You wrote: " << S <<'\n';
    cout << "Even(including 0) positioned character(s) 
    of " << S << " is(are) " << even <<'\n';
    cout << "Odd positioned character(s) of " << S << 
    " is(are) " << odd <<'\n';
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! An answer here will be very helpful also.

Comment: The range based for does not work as you expect: It does not iterate with a running index, but the elements of the container. In your case, the actual characters of the string

Comment: @king_nak Can you kindly elaborate it a bit and recommend a fix, please? A reference to another webpage where I can find a clear instruction of how to do it will also be very helpful.

Comment: Since you don't really benefit from the range based for loop I would just use a regular for loop with `j` being the index. for(int j = 0; j < S.length(); ++j) { ... }

Comment: @drescherjm I did that. See the commented part in the code. But Bjarne was suggesting using range-based for loop in [CPPCON 2017 keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fX2W3nNjJIo). I was trying to do that.

Comment: Was the suggestion for this specific problem? A range based for is not the best solution for all situations.

Comment: @drescherjm he explained that too. but one compelling reason to use it, as i understood from his talk, over natural for is it is less clumsy and thus has lower chances of committing errors while writing it. certainly it is less general, Bjarne mentions that. If you have some time, listen to the lecture, it is so good! :)

Comment: I think the range based for it is more clumsy in this situation. There is an alternate way to fix your original code however. Declare `j` outside the range based for and increment it inside. Then adjust your range based loop `for (auto ch : S){` and use ch instead of `S[j]` in your push_back() calls.

Comment: @drescherjm I am too newbie in C++ to understand what you are suggesting. Can you write a code snippet in the answer to clarify it? If you get time, of course, thank you. To me it seems you are suggesting a method similar to Peter's answer, but probably I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range-based for loop iterates over the elements of a container.  'j' in your code is a character in the string, not an index.  Try this:

```
for (auto character : S)
{
  if (even.length() > odd.length())
  {
    odd.push_back(character);
  }
  else
  {
    even.push_back(character);
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a very clever implementation of even and odd, imo! Thank you! Yes, it clarified my confusion also.